# Effect of rapid switching between charging and discharging of Lithium batteries

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, lithium, lifepo4

I have made a DIY off-grid solar generator that utilizes an Arduino to determine when to dump excess energy to a water heating load.
I have programmed the Arduino to activate the load circuit when the cells reach 3.5 V.

My concern is that due to voltage sag of the battery, the instant the load is applied the Arduino will sense a lower voltage and disconnect the load.

This will cause the load to be turned on and off rapidly as the voltage sags below 3.5 V and then bounces back up to 3.5 V, putting the LiFePO4 cells through rapid cycles of charging then discharging. I am going to test this to determine at which frequency the cycling takes place, although I am sure this will be dependent on the power being provided by the solar array.

- Will this rapid switching between charging the batteries and discharging the batteries cause any sort of degradation?
- Is it possible that this could cause waste heat generation and side chain reactions that accelerate the aging of the battery?

I am considering adding a bank of capacitors and using a PWM output to smooth out the alternating current. I am still uncertain if any of that is necessary as I do no know the extent to which this is a concern for my battery. I did check the setup and determined that the load is switching at around 0.4 Hz.

Comment: so, since you've noticed this might be problematic, why are you even asking? It sounds like a very simple modification to the arduino firmware to add a bit of hysteresis.

Comment: Also, logically, the voltage across the batteries can only *increase* when they're being charged (temperature variations aside). Why even start dumping energy before the cell is fully charged? That sounds like a bad idea. Lithium Battery charging state is not completely determined by voltage alone!

Comment: I'm asking because I would like to know if this is a real concern before I work to try to solve it.  Adding hysteresis does not really solve the problem, only changes the frequency of the charging discharging cycling.  It may be that that is in fact only worsening the issue.

Comment: It is not true that the voltage can only increase when being charged.  On a short time scale if you remove the load from a battery, you will see a sudden increase in voltage.

Comment: I never said I would be dumping energy before the cells are charged.  The whole idea is to detect full charge, and then activate the dump load.  
Yes, state of charge is not entirely determined by voltage, however to keep track of amperage into and out of the battery would have required a current shunt and added a great deal of complexity to this project.  If you view the voltage vs SOC for a LiFePo4 battery you will see a rapid rise in voltage as the battery climbs above 90% SOC, I can use this "knee" in the curve as a fairly reliable indicator that the battery is at a high level of charge.

Comment: I tested the setup using my benchtop power supply(it isn't a perfect test, because the supply is limited to only 300 watts, while the panels are capable of 1200watts).  What I found was that the load was switching on and off twice every 5 seconds, so about 0.4Hz frequency.

Comment: This could be viewed as a 0.4 Hz AC current(although not symmetrical and not sinusoidal).  This AC current is the cause of my concern.  I am considering whether using a PWM output to the load dump, controlled by a PID control function, may help.

Comment: The best solution I can think of would be a PWM output to the SSR, and smoothed out by a bank of properly sized capacitors.  Again, I may be wasting time and money if it turns out that there is no concern to begin with.

Comment: *On a short time scale if you remove the load from a battery, you will see a sudden increase in voltage.* And that's **exactly** the kind of problem a bit of temporal hysteresis solves! So, really add hysteresis. No, you don't add *any* complexity to the system by requiring a charge state detection; your battery charging circuitry **must** have that anyway, unless you like Lithium fires.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what it is you are suggesting.  "this is exactly the kind of problem a bit of temporal hysteresis solves!"  -what problem?  
Voltage sag is not really a "problem".  It is a reality of battery chemistry.

Comment: the problem that you "misdetect" the voltage raise due to reduced load as a situation where you should dump energy.

Comment: I can assure you there is no risk of fire due to overcharge of any one cell.  I have a BMS that will cut off charge circuit if any one cell reaches a voltage beyond 3.6 V.  For LiFePo4 this is a very safe upper limit.  Communicating state of charge from my BMS to my arduino is not a simple task and I will not be pursuing that possibility.  The arduino is not intended to protect the battery, so I'm not concerned about accurate SOC detection from the arduino for safety.  The BMS handles that task.

Comment: I'm not certain there is a problem.  That is why I am asking the question of my original post.

Answer (score 2):

Since your Arduino "knows" when the dump load is active (it controls that state, after all), it needs to have two different switching thresholds. The unloaded batteries have 3.5V across them, and, say, 3.4V across them when loaded.

Then if the load is active, the threshold required to disconnect the load should be should be somewhat under 3.4V.

If the load is inactive, the threshold to engage it should be 3.5V.

This is simply hysteresis, implemented in the Arduino's software.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to dump excess energy, you can either short circuit or open circuit the output of the solar cells.
In your typical application this should be open circuit, so no current will flow in your circuit. The  arduino will sense the high voltage. You can also try to add a hysteris function to start charging at certain point below open circuit state.

Answer (score 0):

Rapid charging and discharging may improve the cycle life of Li-ion batteries.
It's called pulsed current charging, there are several studies on that.

A study found 12 kHz and 50% duty cycle is the best at improve the cycle life.
https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/11/8/2162

Comment: The question is about [lithium iron phosphate batteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_iron_phosphate_battery), not [Li-ion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it seems there is no downside to lithium iron phosphate batteries:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6646717